# Wordpress reset meta fields when updating elementor page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating an elementor custom widget that retrieves custom post type in a defined order.

I am mimicking the same logic I used in another website that is working perfectly fine. however, I noticed that on this website every time I edit the page using elementor, the custom post type (CPT latest post meta data get earased.

I am not able to identify what is the issue so I would be very grateful if another pair of eyes can help me identify the issue.

The Code I am using:

````
public function render() {
        
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        $id       = $this->get_id();

        //Compare Dates to pull only future events
        $meta_queries['future_events'] = 
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'date_from',       // Check the start date field
                    'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),     // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                    'compare' => '>=',              // Return the ones greater than today's date
                    'type'    => 'DATE'             // Let WordPress know we're working with date
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'date_to',         // Check the start date field
                    'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),     // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                    'compare' => '>=',              // Return the ones greater than today's date
                    'type'    => 'DATE'             // Let WordPress know we're working with date
                )
        );

        $args = array(
            'paged'                     => 1,
            'post_type'                 => 'city',
            'posts_per_page'            => 50,
            'orderby'                   => 'meta_value',
            'meta_key'                  => 'date_from',
            'order'                     => 'ASC',
            'post_status'               => 'publish',
            'meta_query'                =>  $meta_queries 
        );

        $wp_query = new \WP_Query($args);
        if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            $this->displayCities($settings, $wp_query);
        endif;
    }

    protected function displayCities($settings, $wp_query){
        print '<div class="row cities-container">';
        while($wp_query->have_posts()):
            $wp_query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $meta = get_post_custom($post_id);

            $date_from          = $meta['date_from'][0];
            $date_to            = $meta['date_to'][0];
            $hide_date          = $meta['hide_date'][0];
            $date_custom_label  = $meta['date_custom_label'][0];

                //If Hide Date is checked
                if($hide_date === 'on'):
                    $label = $date_custom_label;
                //If from date is equal to end date -> show one date only
                elseif($date_from === $date_to || empty($date_to)):
                    $label = date('M d, Y' , strtotime($date_from));
                //Date From is different than Date To
                elseif(!empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to) ):
                    $label = date('M d, Y' , strtotime($date_from)) .' - '. date('M d, Y' , strtotime($date_to)) ;
                    ?><div class="col-sm-<?=$settings['number_of_columns'];?>">
                            <a class="btn btn-h d-block" href="<? print get_post_permalink($post_id);?>">
                                <div class="row d-flex <?= $settings['align_items'];?>">
                                    <div class="icon-container">
                                        <img src="<?=$settings['icon']['url'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="city-information col text-start">
                                        <?= get_the_title() .', '. $label;?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div><?php 

                endif;
        endwhile;
        print '</div>';
    } ```
````

Comment: what do you mean by "post metadata"? are you referring to the custom fields? so when you update the page in the ELEMENTOR editor page these meta data get erased?

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I meant,

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is running in a similar situation,

the issue was that I was not validating the nonce on my custom fields, that's why every time I update the elementor page which includes a section that has this custom post type, it gets erased, by adding the nonce solved my issue.